# Ionic Phone App. Set alarm that survives reboot. Open App when alarm fires

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, alarm

I'm new to [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) and building an alarm app.

How do I set an alarm and have it survive reboot?
How does the alarm activate the app to a certain ui state?

I found [this](https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-wakeuptimer), but it has [this problem](https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-wakeuptimer/issues/9)

[This](http://ngcordova.com/) looked promising, but I didn't see an alarm function.

[These](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.chromium.backgroundapp) [two](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.chromium.alarms) Cordova plugins looked promising, but they don't support IOS.

What's the best strategy?  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On iOS there is **no way** to open your app out of the blue without the user's doing it manually (or calling it from another app). *-Unless you are creating a jailbroken app*
The closest you can get is to set a [Local Notification](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/) to pop up at the time that your alarm is supposed to go off. It will trigger a Push-like Notification that should be reboot persistent. Once it popped, if the user decides to tap on it, it will open your app.

Comment: That's probably why I couldn't find it :-)